# Multi module dependencies in maven EAR?

Tags: maven, multi-module, maven-ear-plugin

I'm new to Maven and I'm converting current EAR application into Maven. It is a multi module project (ear, ejb, web, utility).

Some utility modules depend on other utility modules. I don't want Maven to add version number into modules final JARs. So in EAR's `POM.XML`

I use `<bundleFileName>` option where I set the name of the final JAR. Problem is that generated `MANIFEST.MF` file of module which is dependent 
on this module still uses version number in JAR file name.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is excerpt of EAR's pom.xml

```
<jarModule >
  <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>batch</artifactId>
  <bundleFileName>batch.jar</bundleFileName>
</jarModule >
```

Here is excerpt of module's pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>batch</artifactId>
  <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<build>
<finalName>util</finalName>
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>      
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The result util's MANIFEST.MF contains batch-1.0.jar
But I'd like it to contain batch.jar as mentioned in EAR's pom.xml

Comment: Your EAR is named util? batch-1.0.jar is dependency to util.jar, not EAR!

Answer (score 0):

When you release this ear, you will deploy these modules with the same version?

If yes, then you can use it:

For example: project structure:

```
-EAR
 pom.xml
 --web-module
   pom.xml
 --ejb-module
   pom.xml
```

Imagine that web-module has ejb-module dependency, then you can  add in web-module project this dependency:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>your.groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>your.groupId</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
   </dependency>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I edited my question for better clafification. Could you please take a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to override the finalName in the configuration of maven-jar-plugin? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#finalName